# How do I convert my image file to a blob? Getting "ReferenceError: Blob is not defined" when using image-conversion module

Tags: node.js, image, blob

I have a multipart/form-data form on my frontend which when submitted sends an image file to my NodeJS server. This part works, however, what I want to do next is to compress the image so I found a node module which does this for me. The problem is that the method from that module needs the image file to be a "Blob" which is something I am unfamiliar with. What is this "Blob" and how can I convert my image file to a blob to satistfy the method?

```
// The module:
const imageConversion = require("image-conversion")

// Code from my form submitted POST route:
router.post("/submit-review", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const img = req.files?.img;
    const result = await imageConversion.compressAccurately(img, { // here I am getting "ReferenceError: Blob is not defined"
      size: 100, // 100kb
      accuracy: 0.9, // 90kb - 110kb
      type: img.mimetype,
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
    });
    // here I will upload the compressed image to my mongoDB database, but thats not part of my question.
    res.json({ success: true });
  } 
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "unknown" });
  }
});
```

Comment: The https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-conversion package you're using isn't geared for backend use. `Blob`s are a browser API.

Comment: Oh, I see, would it be a bad idea to handle the image conversion on the frontend then? Or should I find a different module? And if so do you have any recommendations? @AKX

Comment: Node has his own format for binary data called Buffer (different from ArrayBuffer) https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: You can't trust the frontend to have done the conversion, so if you want to be sure, do it in the backend. You'd need a different module than that.